# Planck Units of the Universe

Tags: universe, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

Is it a coincidence, or is it chosen this way, that the size of the width of the universe is approximately 10^61 planck lengths, the mass is 10^61 planck mass, and the age is 10^61 planck time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of the universe is characterized by the current expansion rate $H_0$, the so-called Hubble parameter.

Let us be very lazy and work in natural units, where $\hbar$,$c$ and $8\pi G$ is set to unity ($\hbar=c=8\pi G=1$). Then automatically everything is expressed in dimensionless factors of the (reduced) Planck units, because these are the three constants that make up all of the Planck units.
When we make the simplifying assumption that the expansion rate is always the same, the age of the universe is in general roughly just the inverse of the expansion rate (for *time*, there are no factors of $c$ missing here, so this would be true also in S.I. units):$$t=\frac{1}{H_0}.$$
Since roughly (!) the size of the observable universe is just the distance that light can travel during the age of the universe, the radius is just the speed of light times the age, but since we set $c=1$, this is also just
$$R=\frac{1}{H_0}.$$ We observe the observable universe to be very close to the so-called critical density, an observation that implies the conclusion that the universe is nearly flat. Would it be much denser, it would have collapsed very early, would it be much less dense, nothing interesting regarding structure formation would have happened.
The critical density today can be expressed (with $8\pi G$ explicitly given) as $$ρ_\mathrm{crit,0}=\frac{3H_0^2}{8\pi G},$$ but in natural units this is just $$ρ_\mathrm{crit,0,n.u.}=3H_0^2.$$ Now since the universe is at critical density, the mass of the universe is just (skipping prefactors) $$M\sim\rho_\mathrm{crit,0}R^3\sim \frac{3H_0^2}{H_0^3}=\frac{3}{H_0}.$$ So you see that radius, age and mass of the observable universe in Planck units (!) (Planck length, Planck time, Planck mass, respectively) have the same prefactor given by $1/H_0$. As you may have already guessed, $1/H_0$ in Planck units is $\approx 10^{61}$.

The real question is: Why is the universe so close to the critical density? Inflation tries to answer this.

Comment: H_0 is merely the value of H right now. Does the answer change as the universe expands?

Comment: $H_0$ was bigger in the past, so the pre-factor being roughly $10^{61}$ is true now, but the value was smaller in the past. It seems the universe is now already dominated by something that is called dark energy, which leads to exponential expansion. In perfect exponential expansion (i.e. some time in the far future), the value of $H$ stays constant, despite the growth of the universe. This means the actual pre-factors in front of your rough estimate will change over time, but I would need to do the math to tell you in which manner. :-)

Comment: I realize that this is 2 weeks old now.  I might suggest that in choosing parameters to normalize to get ***universal*** natural units, I would suggest: $$\begin{align} c&=1 \\ \hbar&=1 \\ 4\pi G&=1 \\ \epsilon_0&=1 \\ \end{align}$$ This, then, normalizes ***both*** the speed of propagation in free space ***and*** the characteristic impedance of propagation in free space of both EM radiation and of gravitational radiation.  That would leave a $2$ wherever $8\pi G$ appears, such as the Einstein field equation.

Answer (score -1):

No mystery.

You are describing the mass of only the VISIBLE universe. (The entire universe may be infinite in size, thus its mass would also be infinite.) But you're comparing observable aspects all of which were quantified when conceived.